# Correct usage of Iron router?

Tags: node.js, meteor, iron-router

I'm currently beginning with Meteor and the Iron router. I'm trying to make a multi-page application using Iron router. I've already been able to make some basic structure, but I've also noticed, that even before changing to a new page, Meteor sends all the code for the current application, which is not exactly, what I want.
My question is: Should I use RouteControllers to store all the page logic? If not, how can I prevent sending the code?

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: That's how Meteor works. It sends down all the compiled HTML and JavaScript that the client will ever need to render the application, and the browser stores the application in its cache. Then when running the application, you can subscribe to DDP publications, and the server just sends down JSON data with which the client can do whatever it wants. This way, you can actually store the client app on a caching proxy and let Meteor just send JSON data. Iron Router does not change how the client bundle works. It just interacts with the HTML5 History API and manages your DDP subscriptions.

Comment: - when you say "Meteor sends all the code..." do you mean "code" or "data"? As @sbking says, you the whole app (code) is always downloaded on start, but you can manage what data is sent to the client app based on which view is displayed.

Comment: ok, so it is supposed to send the code, but what if I have a login template and a dashboard template, and I in the dashboard's js file I've got a publishing function, which sends some data. Can I chose, when to publish this data?